# Getting the key in nested dictionary by calling the value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi am new in python and this is my code

If i enter the 'teacher'(key) the output is class A but what i want is when i enter the value which is teacher name like krinny the output is class B how can i do that

```
class1 = {
    "class A" : {"teacher" : "simbahan", "Room" : 201 , "Schedule" : "MWF" },
    "class B" : {"teacher" : "krinny", "Room" : 202 , "Schedule" : "TTh" }}

def view2():
    x = input("Enter teacher name: ")
    def findClass(name, class1):
        return next((k for k, v in class1.items() if name in v), None)

    print(findClass(x, class1))
view2()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the value of current value in the dictionary, and as you know the value is also a dictionary you can check it again like this:

```
def findClass(name, class1):
        return [i for i in class1 if class1[i]['teacher'] == x][0]
```

**NOTE** it will return a list where the teachers name is x

for a more detailed answer:

```
for i in class1:
    if class1[i]['teacher'] == x:
        return i
    return None
```

Your final code would be:

```
class1 = {
    "class A": {"teacher": "simbahan", "Room": 201, "Schedule": "MWF"},
    "class B": {"teacher": "krinny", "Room": 202, "Schedule": "TTh"}}
def view2():
    x = input("Enter teacher name: ")

    def findClass(name, class1):
        return [i for i in class1 if class1[i]['teacher'] == x][0]
    print(findClass(x, class1))
view2()
```

Comment: Its say  when i run it TypeError: findClass() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'name' and 'class1'

Comment: Which one did you run??

Comment: I did this code but i don't know what happened why nothing happen             
class11 = {
    "class A" : {"teacher" : "simbahan", "Room" : 201 , "Schedule" : "MWF" },
    "class B" : {"teacher" : "krinny", "Room" : 202 , "Schedule" : "TTh" }}
def view2():
    x = input("Enter teacher name: ")
    def findClass(name, class1):
        return [i for i in class1 if class1[i]['teacher'] == x][0]
        for i in class1:
           if class1[i]['teacher'] == x:
                return i
           return None
view2() am sorry am really new in python and really appreciate what you doing

Comment: No no, i mean use one of these... Check the updated answer please

Comment: Copy the last code snippet and see if there is an answer, if you get IndexError remove the [0] or make a try except block ,if you dont know about try except , let me know

Comment: It work thanks a lot really appreciate it man i really like this community

Comment: @roiden i will be glad if you [mark answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)

Comment: Hi its me again i have other question if okay when i put the right input like roiden i get the results i want like class A but if i put wrong input nothing but i want when i put a wrong input the result is none.        class1 = {
    "class A": {"teacher": "simbahan", "Room": 201, "Schedule": "MWF"},
    "class B": {"teacher": "krinny", "Room": 202, "Schedule": "TTh"}}
def view2():
    x = input("Enter teacher name: ")

    def findClass(name, class1):
        return [i for i in class1 if class1[i]['teacher'] == x][0]
    print(findClass(x, class1))
view2()

Comment: Read my comment of try except above, do you know what is exception handling?